# Custom module route to config form deleted, now the site is down

Tags: 8, routes

So I have a custom module Domaincheck which had an admin configuration form. Since that one is not needed at all, I decided to clean up and delete the form and route.

That resulted in a `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException` for the "domaincheck.form" route, probably because in my eagerness I forgot to uninstall the module first. So I added the deleted stuff again, but still no dice, the site never came back. Anytime I tried to log in as admin, the `RouteNotFoundException` would fire and kill the complete site. Cleaning up the cache via Drush or by hand in the database itself did not work, either.

So I tried to disable the module with Drush, and since that did not work, I foolishly googled and read that I should also delete the entry in the "key_value" table which corresponds to my module. I did that, which now produced a new error:

> InvalidArgumentException: No check has been registered for
>   access_check.permission in
>   Drupal\Core\Access\CheckProvider->loadCheck() (line 97 of
>   core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/CheckProvider.php)

So right now, I think I'm truly f-ed. I tried inserting the key_value-entry again, but that did not work. Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Full error messages are:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException:
>   Route "domaincheck.form" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName()
>   (line 201 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getRoute('domaincheck.form')
>   (Line: 130)
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->getPathFromRoute('domaincheck.form',
>   Array) (Line: 68)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MetadataBubblingUrlGenerator->getPathFromRoute('domaincheck.form',
>   Array) (Line: 790) Drupal\Core\Url->getInternalPath() (Line: 135)
>   Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator->generate('Domain Check Tool
>   settings', Object) (Line: 94)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Link::preRenderLink(Array)
>   call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 501)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 117)
>   __TwigTemplate_0a18ab003712dad4eb09167d0100830dd1458c413a526205fe5f96e0a321828e->getmenu_links(Array,
>   Object, 1) (Line: 124)
>   __TwigTemplate_0a18ab003712dad4eb09167d0100830dd1458c413a526205fe5f96e0a321828e->getmenu_links(Array,
>   Object, 0) (Line: 60)
>   __TwigTemplate_0a18ab003712dad4eb09167d0100830dd1458c413a526205fe5f96e0a321828e->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 455) Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 422) Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 434)
>   Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('core/modules/toolbar/templates/menu--toolbar.html.twig',
>   Array) (Line: 384)
>   Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('menu__toolbar',
>   Array) (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1)
>   (Line: 195) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line:
>   151) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}()
>   (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
>   (Line: 152) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array) (Line:
>   340)
>   _toolbar_do_get_rendered_subtrees(Array) call_user_func('_toolbar_do_get_rendered_subtrees', Array)
>   (Line: 378) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line:
>   195) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 151)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render\{closure}() (Line:
>   582) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object,
>   Object) (Line: 152) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderPlain(Array)
>   (Line: 310) toolbar_get_rendered_subtrees() (Line: 368)
>   _toolbar_get_subtrees_hash() (Line: 167) toolbar_toolbar() call_user_func_array('toolbar_toolbar', Array) (Line: 403)
>   Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll('toolbar')
>   (Line: 81) Drupal\toolbar\Element\Toolbar::preRenderToolbar(Array)
>   call_user_func(Array, Array) (Line: 378)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 450)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 195)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 501)
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter(Object, Array,
>   'html', NULL, 1) (Line: 104)
>   __TwigTemplate_a8fce0a6cb375de3aaad3497c3acdfe7f5c1de05ab269b955db23ce7f7fb8653->doDisplay(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 455) Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array,
>   Array) (Line: 422) Twig\Template->display(Array) (Line: 434)
>   Twig\Template->render(Array) (Line: 64)
>   twig_render_template('themes/contrib/bootstrap_sass/templates/layout/html.html.twig',
>   Array) (Line: 384)
>   Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array)
>   (Line: 437) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line:
>   195) Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 147)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}()
>   (Line: 582)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
>   (Line: 148)
>   Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse(Array,
>   Object, Object) (Line: 90)
>   Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray(Object,
>   'kernel.view', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
>   'kernel.view', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.view',
>   Object) (Line: 156)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
>   (Line: 68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 106)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 85)
>   Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 693) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

And:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.InvalidArgumentException:
>   No check has been registered for access_check.permission in Drupal\Core\Access\CheckProvider->loadCheck()
>   (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Access/CheckProvider.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->performCheck('access_check.permission',
>   Object) (Line: 135) Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->check(Object,
>   Object, Object, 1) (Line: 112)
>   Drupal\Core\Access\AccessManager->checkRequest(Object, Object, 1)
>   (Line: 109)
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess(Object) (Line:
>   94) Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object)
>   (Line: 113)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   Object) (Line: 127)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
>   (Line: 68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 52)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 693) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

I'm thankful for any advice you guys can give me. This project should have rolled out end of the week...

Comment: Did you try to enable the module and disable it again? Did you try a database backup?

Comment: Tried enabling and disabling with drush (since I can't get to the admin interface) and did not work. And I don't have a database backup, which really is my own fault.

Comment: Put the module back and re-enable it via Drush, flush caches, what happens then when you access the site? And what does `drush wd-show` return you then? **Never ever do those things on production again without having a database backup!!!** You may also consider asking your hosting provider for a database and/or file backup.

Comment: After deleting the form & route all you had to do was clear the cache. Technically with the info you've provided, doing `drush cr` should fix the issue.